# how to hide the ugliest vinyl flooring ever (renter friendly)

Tags: bathroom, kitchens, vinyl-flooring

so my apartment was flooded and the vinyl flooring in the bathroom was damaged. the management said they were going to replace it and didn’t for about a year. i finally started threatening to complain to the county and so they quickly scheduled a contractor and put in the vinyl while i wasn’t home. they did not show me the tile before.  i used to have cream/white vinyl and now it’s dark brown with some water damage looking pattern. and it’s warm brown too, while my floors are cool gray… it’s truly shockingly bad and i’m 99% sure they chose this and installed it just to spite me because it’s not in any other unit. anyway, ultimately i have to spend my own money to cover it up now. it’s just not tolerable.

i was looking at peel and stick tile but i know it’s hard to work with. also baby splat mats but they’re not big enough. also rugs would be tough since obviously it needs to be cleanable. i just need something white or cream that covers up MOST of the floor. i can put small rugs where the edges are or something. or anti fatigue mats. but the majority has to be covered.

if anyone has any ideas or advice please tell me. i’m leaning towards the adhesive tile because honestly even if i do a terrible job it just can’t be worse than what’s there now.

Comment: There are rugs that *can* be thrown in the wash...

Comment: If this is a rental, the management isn't required to check with you before replacing anything.

Comment: there ARE washable rugs but the size they’d be to cover the area would not fit into my washing machine.

Comment: I'm voting to close because the question is too broad and somewhat about decorating, which is off topic here. Please see https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. I've downvoted for the same reason and because none of the sentences are properly capitalized, making it difficult to read.

Comment: Adhesive tile is a Very Bad Idea as a renter. It's not easily/cleanly removable and will cost you the security deposit.

Comment: There's a difference between visual aesthetics and quality of workmanship.  If the work is done first-rate just with a color you don't like, and you downgrade the quality (but in a color you do like), when you move out you'll need to pay to bring it back to first-rate.  Your opinion about "to spite you" makes no sense, as you could give notice tomorrow and now they have to find a tenant.  How about rugs?

Answer (score 6):

One idea you could try is to get a piece of linoleum of a desired color & pattern big enough to cover the whole bathroom, then carefully trim it into place. Use double side carpet tape to hold it down at the edges, in various places in the middle, and the entrances. If the entrances have screw-down cover transition strips, you might unscrew them, ease the linoleum under the strip then screw them back down.

When move out time comes, pull up your linoleum and peel off the carpet tape. A little rubbing alcohol can help unstick the tape.